# clear html form with angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to clear my input values in html form  when you press submit.
the function is in the controller.
i tried to do: $scope.name = "" or null (for every input) but its don't work.
This is the html file:

```
    <label for="messageName">Message Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="message.name"  name="message.name" required/>

    <label for="text">Text:</label>
    <input type="textarea" ng-model="message.text" name="message.text" required/>

    <label for="images">Images:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="message.images" name="message.images" required/>

    <label for="template">Template:</label>
    <input list="template" ng-model="message.template" name="message.template" required/>
    <datalist id="template">
        <option value="template1">
        <option value="template2">
        <option value="template3">
    </datalist>

    <label for="millisecToShow">Millisec To Show:</label>
    <input type="number" min="1000" max="10000" ng-model="message.millisecToShow" name="message.millisecToShow" required/>

    <label for="timeFrame">Time Frame:</label>
    <label for="TimeStart">Start Time:</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" ng-model="message.startDateTime" name="message.startDateTime" required/>
    <label for="DateStart">End Time:</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" ng-model="message.endDateTime" name="message.endDateTime" required/>

    <label for="days">Days:</label><br>
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="message.sunday" name="message.days" value="Sunday">Sunday<br>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="message.monday" name="message.days" value="Monday">Monday<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="message.tuesday" name="message.days" value="Tuesday">Tuesday<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="message.wednesday" name="message.days" value="Wednesday">Wednesday<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="message.thursday" name="message.days" value="Thursday">Thursday<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="message.friday" name="message.days" value="Friday">Friday<br> 
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="message.saturday" name="message.days" value="Saturday">Saturday<br> 
    </form>

    <label for="screenId">Screen ID:</label>
    <input list="screenId" ng-model="message.screenId" name="message.screenId" required/>
    <datalist id="screenId">
        <option value="screen1">
        <option value="screen2">
        <option value="screen3">
    </datalist>

    <button ng-click="createButton()">Create</button>
```

And this is the controller:

```
angular.module('CreateCtrl', []).controller('CreateController', function($scope, superService) {

    $scope.createButton = function() {
        superService.insert($scope.message).then(function (result)
            if (result == "true") {
                alert('Create successful');
                $scope.tagline = 'Create successful';
                return result.data;
            }
            else {
                $scope.tagline = 'Cannot create message';
            }
        });
    };
});
```

I want to remove the input after sending the file.
thanks (:

Comment: Show us what you tried, and tell us precisely what happened. Here's a reduced, functional example: http://plnkr.co/edit/VpvJDjT5BhjHFpucVOEj?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that all of the fields refer to `$scope.message.*`, wouldn't it be easier to just clean up the whole `message` object like this?

```js
if (result === "true") {
    alert('Create successful');
    $scope.tagline = 'Create successful';

    // cleaning up
    $scope.message = {
        name: null,
        text: null,
        images: null,
        template: null
    };

    return result.data;
}
```

In fact, if you want to wipe the whole object clean, if it were me I would just go for `$scope.message = {};` and be done with it.